# Room Rxjava Single as Delete Response

Tags: android, android-room

I am faceing some issues with compile time errors from the Room Library.

I am using Version: 2.1.0-alpha02

The following Dao causes the error:

```
@Dao()
public interface WorkoutExerciseDao {

    [......]
    @Update()
    Single<Integer> updateWorkout(final WorkoutExercise... workoutExercises);


    @Delete
    Single<Integer> deleteWorkouts(final WorkoutExercise... user);

    @Query("DELETE FROM workout_exercise_table WHERE id  IN(:exerciseIds)")
    Single<Integer> deleteWorkouts(final long... exerciseIds);
}
```

Currently the first @Delete annotated Method compiles fine and works as expected. If I add the second one(Delete inside the query method) it breaks compilation with an error:

> Deletion methods must either return void or return int (the number of
>   deleted rows).

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Here's single `@Delete`-annotated method. What do you mean by "second"?

Comment: I meant the Query one that contains a DELETE Statement. sorry, should have been clearer about that

Comment: I suppose that Room's RxJava codegeneration isn't smart enough to adapt `@Query` with `DELETE` method to `Single<Integer>`. Have you tried to change it to `int` or `Integer`?

Comment: Just wondering as the same error occured for the Delete annotated method when I returned Single<Long>. So it does seem to be able to map those for Delete methods

Comment: Yep, seems and it does not expect neither `Long`, `Short` and `Byte`

Comment: maybe try 2.1.0-alpha04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are right and I had this problem. I don't know reason but I know there isn't any way in latest version of room to handle this problem and when you use query for `DELETE` it says return type must be void or int but if you want use `RX` for `DELETE` query you can do like this but maybe not best way:
first convert `interface` to `abstract class` and also all methods to `abstract method` then

```
@Dao
public abstract class WorkoutExerciseDao {

    @Update()
    abstract Single<Integer> updateWorkout(final WorkoutExercise... workoutExercises);

    @Delete
    abstract Single<Integer> deleteWorkouts(final WorkoutExercise... user);

    @Query("DELETE FROM workout_exercise_table WHERE id  IN(:exerciseIds)")
    abstract Integer deleteWorkouts(final long... exerciseIds);

    Single<Integer> deleteWorkoutsById(final long... exerciseIds) {
        return Single.create(emitter -> {
            emitter.onSuccess(deleteWorkouts(exerciseIds));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing something like this as a workaround in the meantime. I submitted a bug report in the official tracker and it got promoted. Maybe this will be fixed by the time the non beta/alpha version gets released.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("DELETE FROM yourDB")
void delete() : Completable
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use **AndroidX**

Migrate your project to AndroidX first refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), the easy way is to right click your project folder make sure it is in ***projects*** perspective, right click the folder and click **Refactor** and there should be an option "**Migrate to AndroidX**".

[image]

After migrating your project to AndroidX you can now add the AndroidX dependencies in  your app level gradle.

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version" // kapt for Kotlin
// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#room) for adding latest version dependencies for Room.